# Money does not charge using Authorize.Net

Tags: python, python-3.x, authorize.net

Using Authorize.Net I got such response

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<createTransactionResponse
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">
    <refId>ven-730</refId>
    <messages>
        <resultCode>Ok</resultCode>
        <message>
            <code>I00001</code>
            <text>Successful.</text>
        </message>
    </messages>
    <transactionResponse>
        <responseCode>1</responseCode>
        <authCode>N4WBHD</authCode>
        <avsResultCode>Y</avsResultCode>
        <cvvResultCode>P</cvvResultCode>
        <cavvResultCode>2</cavvResultCode>
        <transId>some_id</transId>
        <refTransID>some_ref</refTransID>
        <transHash />
        <testRequest>0</testRequest>
        <accountNumber>XXXX1602</accountNumber>
        <accountType>MasterCard</accountType>
        <messages>
            <message>
                <code>1</code>
                <description>This transaction has been approved.</description>
            </message>
        </messages>
        <transHashSha2 />
    </transactionResponse>
</createTransactionResponse>
```

But nothing charged from the credit card. Where the problem could be? Because of mastercard / different country / anything else?

Comment: There isn't enough information here. Are you in production? Or using the sandbox account? Did you confirm the transaction has settled? How are you checking to see if the card was charged? How long did you wait?

Comment: @JohnConde 1) In production 2) I don't know how to confirm that transaction has settled 3) I'm using a online banking to check the card money amount 4) About an hour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An hour is not enough time to see a transaction hit the charged account. Transactions don't actually become official until they are settled with the processing bank. Transactions are settled once per day, typically late in the evening. At that point you will see the transaction appear on the credit card.